# Firebase security rule error storage/unauthorized

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

When I always write to the Firebase storage, this problem appears to me: “storage/unauthorized 403.” I tried to search for how to solve this problem, but I did not find any solution to it, and in this code there is the security rule for firebase

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

The following code is the JavaScript code that I used

```
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  authDomain: "xxxxxxxxxxxx.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "xxxxxxxxxxx",
  storageBucket: "xxxxxxxxxxxx.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  appId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  measurementId: "G-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
};
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  var fileName = "m10pl";
  var storage = firebase.storage();
  var fileRef = storage.ref().child("Images/" + fileName + ".jpg");
  fileRef.delete()
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Deleted");
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error("fix it ", error);
  });

  let storageRef = firebase.storage().ref("Images/" + fileName + ".jpg");
  let uploadTask = storageRef.put(fileItem);
  uploadTask.on("state_changed",(snapshot)=>{
      percentval = parseInt(Math.floor((snapshot.bytesTransferred/snapshot.totalBytes) *100));
      $("p.work____").html("Please Wait... (Dont Close Browser) " + percentval + "%");
      console.log(snapshot);
    },(error)=>{
      console.log(error);
  },()=>{
  uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((url)=>{
    console.log(`URL ${url}`);
    url = url.replaceAll("&","%26");
    var t = "m";
    var uid = 10;
    $.ajax({
      url:"/console/system.php",
      type:"post",
      data:`app_resource=icon&res_t=${t}&res_uid=${uid}&url=${url}`,
      success:function(respone){
        $("p.work____").html("");
        console.log(respone);
        if(respone == "success"){
          $("p.sucs____").html("The icon has been uploaded successfully");
        }else{
          $("p.error____").html(respone);
        }
      }
    })
  })
})
}
```

Maybe the problem is that request.auth is always null

Firebase update used:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.3.0/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.3.0/firebase-storage.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your security rules require that your user is signed in to Firebase Authentication, but your code doesn't sign the user in anywhere. I recommend reading the documentation on [getting started with Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start). For the simplest experience, you can consider [using anonymous sign-in](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth) which works without requiring the user to enter any credentials.